# area should be added without length and breath input value

Tags: angularjs

On changing area value manually by user the result must change accordingly to the manually edited area value. it means if i am giving length and Breath then only area is calculating but i need area should be added when next line is open and area must be take manually without length and Breadth.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
               app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function($scope) {

                    /* Start constants declaration*/
                    $scope.constant = {coeff : "0.003"};
                    /*End constants declaration*/

                    /*Start user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/
                    $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 10, b2 : 10}];
                    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
                         var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
                         $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo});
                    };

                    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
                         var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
                         $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
                    };

                    $scope.sum = function() {
                         var sum = 0;
                         angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
                              sum += choice.l2 * choice.b2;
                         });
                         return sum;
                    }
                    /*End user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/
               });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "data.js"></script>
     <body>
          <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
               <!--Start Input calculation-->
               <form  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">  <br>  {{$index + 1}} :
                    Length:<input type="number" ng-model="choice.l2"  />ft
                    Breadth: <input type="number" ng-model="choice.b2"  />ft
                    Area: <input id="area" type="number" placeholder="Area" value="{{ choice.l2 * choice.b2}}" />sqft
                    <button  ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>
                    <button  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button> </br>
               </form>
               <!--End Input  calculation-->
               <br>  <b>Output</b>
               <br> Area to be treated:  {{sum() + (sum() * 0.05)}}
               <p> chemical: {{(sum() + (sum() * 0.05)) * constant.coeff}}</p>
               <!--end Output calculation-->
          </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is the correct script,after giving area field manually its not working!!

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because of {{choice.l2 * choice.b2}} change it to {{choice.area}} and add a area element in your array , but more importantly (logically) if you want your area to change then you must update your length and breadth. maybe you want to think this through - should you allow the updating of length and breadth if area has been edited Or should you even allow editing the area in the first place?.

Comment: ,this scenario is because if user don't know the length and breadth,so directly he will enter the area field so based on this result must be calculated,i tried your above suggestion but unfortunately its not working!!

Comment: So if the user enters an area manually, will the length and breadth update? If so you have not implemented the logic for that

Comment: if the user enters an area manually,  the length and breadth should not be update,because i need this  manually area value for output calculation,in otherword,while giving l and b area calculate and sum() function will work for output,and same sum() function must be work when we gie the area mannually